# mybatis jdbc select query is not working throws Invalid column index

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am having below issue in mybatis version 3.Please help me to find this.

**Java Code:**

```
@Select("SELECT A.PERSON_ID,A.PERSON_ADDRESS, C.CUSTOMER_NAME," + 
            "       B.CUSTOMER_DOB," + 
            "   FROM PERSON A, CUSTOMER B, CUSTOMER_DETAILS C" + 
            "  WHERE A.CUSTOMER_ID=C.CUSTOMER_ID" + 
            "  AND A.CUSTOMER_ID=B.CUSTOMER_ID (+)" + 
            "  AND C.PERSON_NAME='#{personName, jdbcType=VARCHAR,    mode=IN,  javaType=String}'" + 
            "  AND C.CUSTOMER_ID='#{customerID, jdbcType=VARCHAR,    mode=IN,  javaType=String}'")
    @Results(value = {
       @Result(property = "personId", column = "PERSON_ID"),
       @Result(property = "personAddress", column = "PERSON_ADDRESS"),
       @Result(property = "customerName", column = "CUSTOMER_NAME"),
       @Result(property = "customerDOB", column = "CUSTOMER_DOB")
    })
    List<PersonCustomerDetail> getPersonCustomerByID(@Param("personName") String personName,@Param("customerID") String customerID);
```

**Exception trace:**

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: 
Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='personName', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, 
numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType VARCHAR . 
Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Comment: Could be for the OUTER JOIN. Try to rewrite using LEFT OUTER JOIN and execute in toad or SQL plus

Comment: Nope, that is nothing at all to do with the JPA API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with parameters passing to the query.

When you use expression like `#{parameterName}` to specify a parameter mybatis transforms it to the jdbc parameter placeholder `?` and then sets the parameter by index. For this query:

```
 select * from  a where col = #{param}
```

the query generated by mybatis would be:

```
 select * from a where col = ?
```

Because you quoted the parameter like this:

```
 select * from  a where col = '#{param}'
```

the generated query becomes:

```
 select * from  a where col = '?'
```

And this is treated by JDBC API as a query without any parameters so when mybatis tries to set parameters using JDBC `PreparedStatement` API the error is that parameter index is invalid.

To fix the issue remove the quotes:

```
@Select("SELECT A.PERSON_ID,A.PERSON_ADDRESS, C.CUSTOMER_NAME," + 
    "       B.CUSTOMER_DOB," + 
    "   FROM PERSON A, CUSTOMER B, CUSTOMER_DETAILS C" + 
    "  WHERE A.CUSTOMER_ID=C.CUSTOMER_ID" + 
    "  AND A.CUSTOMER_ID=B.CUSTOMER_ID (+)" + 
    "  AND C.PERSON_NAME=#{personName, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN, javaType=String}" + 
    "  AND C.CUSTOMER_ID=#{customerID, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN, javaType=String}")
```